# Router Guard Issue?

Tags: angular, router, guard, angular-router-guards

I am facing a situation. I have a CanActivate router guard. Usage of the guards causes an unwanted reload of the whole page.

I implemented two versions of the guard and figured out something I do not understand. Can anybody explain the behavior and suggest a solution?
Here is the routing:

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: DashboardComponent,
  children: [{
      path: 'overview',
      component: OverviewComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'profile',
      canActivate: [TestGuard],
      component: ProfileComponent,
    },
  ],
}, ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class MyRoutingModule {}
```

Guard Version 1 (works as expected):

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  CanActivate,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
} from '@angular/router';
import {
  Observable,
  of
} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor() {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable < boolean > {
    return of(true);
  }
}
```

Guard Version 2 (reloads the whole page):

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  CanActivate,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
} from '@angular/router';
import {
  Observable,
  of
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  delay,
  map
} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor() {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable < boolean > {
    return of(true).pipe(
      delay(5000),
      map(answer => answer)
    );
  }
}
```

My problem is I need to call a service (API request). It is simulated by the delay in the second example. But in this case, it causes the reload of the whole page.
What I do not see?

Comment: Here's a link to github. It looks like a bug. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32819#issuecomment-538465250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it is not an issue. It should work. The problem lies somewhere in our project.

It is somehow related to lazy loaded modules. The issue was fixed by using ngxs and reading the needed information from the state.